# Not able to parse XML file containing Chinese content

Tags: java, xml, unicode, cjk

I have an XML file containing Chinese content. But while displaying I am getting question marks. Could somebody look into this issue?

My book.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<book>
  <person>
    <first>密码</first>
    <last>Pai</last>
    <age>22</age>
  </person>
</book>
```

And my code is:

```
public static void main (String argv []){
  DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("book.xml"));
  String strDoc=getStringFromDocument(doc);
  System.out.println(strDoc);
}

public static String getStringFromDocument(Document doc) {
 TransformerFactory transfac = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
 Transformer trans = transfac.newTransformer();
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
 trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(sw);
 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
 trans.transform(source, result);
 String xmlString = sw.toString();
 return xmlString.toString();
}
```

After that I am getting `??`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <book>
    <person>
      <first>??</first>
      <last>Pai</last>
      <age>22</age>
    </person>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code runs fine on my system.  I was able to create a books.xml with chinese characters, run your code on my system and get the correct output.

[update]

Previously I thought your books.xml file was suspect - but I was finally able to reproduce your problem on my system by setting -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1.

Somewhere in your environment you have an incorrect character encoding setting.  Perhaps in the JVM, perhaps in the console where you are displaying the characters.

One way to ensure that you are writing your String as a UTF-8 encoded byte stream is to change:

```
 System.out.println(strDoc);
```

to

```
 System.out.write(strDoc.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

This may or may not fix what you are seeing on the screen.  Your console must also be configured to properly handle UTF-8 encoded data.  But if you write these bytes to a file or socket, you should be able confirm that the bytes match those in your original file.

Comment: where I have to set -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 ?

Comment: Depends on your environment.  From the command just replace "java ..." with "java -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 ...".  Using an IDE just follow the instructions for the IDE and add it to wherever they specify "VM options" or "VM arguments"  when debugging.